# Does foreach loop work more slowly when used with a not stored list or array?

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, loops, foreach

I am wondered at if `foreach` loop works slowly if an unstored list or array is used as an `in` array or `List`.

I mean like that:

```
foreach (int number in list.OrderBy(x => x.Value)
 {
  // DoSomething();
 }
```

Does the loop in this code calculates the sorting every iteration or not?

The loop using stored value:

```
 List<Tour> list = tours.OrderBy(x => x.Value) as List<Tour>;
    foreach (int number in list)
      {
       // DoSomething();
      }
```

And if it does, which code shows the better performance, storing the value or not?

Comment: I think there's no real difference in C#.

Comment: first is better,  As you just have Enumerable collection . Second option actually goes one step more to convert this Enumerable to List<>. But hardly any difference can be spotted

Comment: @Reddy, the example is randomly chosen. But it would be without converting. What would be if there is no converting?

Comment: In every language I've encountered, the loop limits are calculated once at the start of the loop, which is why you iterate backwards (from the end to the start) when deleting items from a list. It wouldn't make any sense to check the bounds on every iteration. So (based on the `foreach` only) both are equivalent. The first will begin execution slightly faster, because the second has to do the conversion (using `as`) before the loop starts, but it's highly unlikely that the difference will be meaningful IRL.

Comment: If you want to know how fast something is, **run it**.  You wrote the code; see how fast it runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is often counter-intuitive, but generally speaking, the option that is best for performance is to wait as long as possible to materialize results into a concrete structure like a list or array. Please keep in mind that this is a generalization, and so there are plenty of cases where it doesn't hold. Nevertheless, the first instinct is better when you avoid creating the list for as long as possible.

To demonstrate with your sample, we have these two options:

```
var list = tours.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
foreach (int number in list)
{
   // DoSomething();
}
```

vs this option:

```
foreach (int number in list.OrderBy(x => x.Value))
{
     // DoSomething();
}
```

To understand what is going on here, you need to look at the [.OrderBy()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method. Reading the linked documentation, you'll see it returns a `IOrderedEnumerable<TSource>` object. With an IOrderedEnumerable, all of the sorting needed for the `foreach` loop is already finished when you first start iterating over the object (and that, I believe, is the crux of your question: No, it does not re-sort on each iteration). Also note that *both samples use the same `OrderBy()` call.* Therefore, both samples have the same problem to solve for ordering the results, and they accomplish it the same way, meaning they take exactly the same amount of time to reach that point in the code.

The difference in the code samples, then, is entirely in using the `foreach` loop directly vs first calling `.ToList()`, because in both cases we start from an `IOrderedEnumerable`. Let's look closely at those differences.

When you call `.ToList()`, what do you think happens? This method is not magic. There is still code here which must execute in order to produce the list. This code *still effectively uses it's own `foreach` loop that you can't see*. Additionally, where once you only needed to worry about enough RAM to handle one object at a time, you are now forcing your program to allocate a new block of RAM large enough to hold references for the entire collection. Moving beyond references, you may also potentially need to create new memory allocations for the full objects, if you were reading a from a stream or database reader before that really only needed one object in RAM at a time. This is an especially big deal on systems where memory is the primary constraint, which is often the case with web servers, where you may be serving and maintaining session RAM for many many sessions, but each session only occasionally uses any CPU time to request a new page.

Now I am making one assumption here, that you are working with something that is not already a list. What I mean by this, is the previous paragraphs talked about needing to convert an IOrderedEnumerable into a List, but not about converting a List into some form of IEnumerable. I need to admit that there is some small overhead in creating and operating the state machine that .Net uses to implement those objects. However, I think this is a *good* assumption. It turns out to be true far more often than we realize. Even in the samples for this question, we're paying this cost regardless, by the simple virtual of calling the `OrderBy()` function.

In summary, there can be some additional overhead in using a raw IEnumerable vs converting to a List, but there probably isn't. Additionally, you are almost certainly saving yourself some RAM by avoiding the conversions to List whenever possible... potentially a **lot** of RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

Yes the foreach statement will seem to work slower.

No your program has the same total amount of work to do so you will not be able to measure a difference from the outside.

What you need to focus on is not using a lazy operation (in this case OrderBy) multiple times without a .ToList or ToArray. In this case you are only using it once(foreach) but it is an easy thing to miss.

Edit: Just to be clear. The as statement in the question will not work as intended but my answer assumes no .ToList() after OrderBy .

Answer (score 0):

This line won't run:

```
List<Tour> list = tours.OrderBy(x => x.Value) as List<Tour>; // Returns null.
```

Instead, you want to store the results this way:

```
List<Tour> list = tours.OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

And yes, the second option (storing the results) will enumerate much faster as it will skip the sorting operation.

Comment: But the sorting time is consumed while sorting it the first time right?

Comment: @Reddy yes. If you take the initial sorting into consideration, the first approach will be the fastest as it will not create an additional list.

Comment: The iteration part with just the `foreach` will be faster when converting to a List first, but most of the time the overall execution time to both sort and iterate the collection will actually be **slower** when you convert to List, meaning this answer is very misleading.